# The search popover tooltip lost the keyword text in Meta

Tags: bug, design, search

The search popover tooltip is missing the keyword in the Meta section. In the Stack Overflow Search screenshot, the keyword texts are displayed correctly.

Screenshot from Meta Stack Exchange:

> [image: Meta]

Screenshot from Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow]

Comment: They seem to display just fine for me here on MSE.

Comment: @V2Blast The `"ff-mono"` class is being used for the keyword text in the popover, causing it to display in a different font-family. I suspect that the font-family wasn't loaded temporarily, leading to the intermittent issue.